# Converting an Array into a Dictionary With Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table and convert it into a dictionary using the TH as the key and the td as the value.

Below is the code to grab the TD and the TH

```
for row in rows:

        td = row.find_all('td')
        th = row.find_all('th')
        row2 = [i.text.replace("\n", "").strip() for i in td]
        print(row2)
        ['', '90315', 'Printmaking I', 'S1', '01(REG-HR)', 'Faletto, Liana', '445', 
        'LS']
        print(headers) 
        #['Class', 'Description', 'Term', 'Schedule', 'Primary Staff > Name', 'Clssrm', 'Name']
```

How do I convert the output into (delete the first blank array item)

```
thisdict = {
  "class": "90315",
  "description": "Printmaking I",
  "term": "S1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete first element of `row2`: (`>>>` is python prompt)

```
>>> del row2[0]
>>> row2
['90315', 'Printmaking I', 'S1', '01(REG-HR)', 'Faletto, Liana', '445', 'LS']
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python
thisdict = {'class':"", 'description':"", 'term':"", ...}
thisdict['class']=row2[1]
thisdict['description']=row2[2]
thisdict['term']=row2[3]
...
```

or if your `headers` contain list of dictionary keys:

```
for i in range(len(headers)):
   thisdict[headers[i]] = row2[i]
```

```
>>> thisdict
{'Term': 'S1', 'Description': 'Printmaking I', 'term': 'S1', 'class': '90315', 'Class': '90315', 'description': 'Printmaking I'}
```